# Перенос объектов одного массива в свойства объекта из другого массива по ID

Tags: javascript

подскажите пожалуйста как из

```
const arr1 = [
            {name: 'aaaaa', id: 1 },
            {name: 'bbbbbb', id: 2 },
            {name: 'ccccc', id: 3 },
            {name: 'aaaasds', id: 4 },
            {name: 'asdsada', id: 5 },
            {name: 'asdsadasd', id: 6 },
        ]
        const arr2 = [
            {name: 'adsaszzc123213', ids: 1 },
            {name: 'bbbbbb', ids: 1 },
            {name: 'ccccc', ids: 6 },
            {name: 'asdas dxc zz ', ids: 2 },
            {name: 'zxc zx czx c', ids: 2 },
            {name: 'zxc zx czx cz', ids: 6 },
            {name: 'adsaszzc123213', ids: 1 },
            {name: '111', ids: 1 },
            {name: 'ccccc', ids: 3 },
            {name: 'zxc dxc zz ', ids: 3 },
            {name: 'zxc zx 111111111czx c', ids: 5 },
            {name: 'zxc zx czx cz', ids: 4 },
        ]
```

сделать

```
const arr1 = [
            {name: 'aaaaa', id: 1,
                childs: [
                    {name: 'adsaszzc123213', ids: 1 },
                    {name: 'bbbbbb', ids: 1 },
                    {name: 'adsaszzc123213', ids: 1 },
                    {name: '111', ids: 1 }
                ]
             },
            {name: 'bbbbbb', id: 2,
                childs: [
                    {name: 'asdas dxc zz ', ids: 2 },
                    {name: 'zxc zx czx c', ids: 2 }
                ]
            },
            {name: 'ccccc', id: 3,
                child: [
                    {name: 'ccccc', ids: 3 },
                    {name: 'zxc dxc zz ', ids: 3 }
                ]
            },
            {name: 'aaaasds', id: 4, childs: [{name: 'zxc zx czx cz', ids: 4 }]},
            {name: 'asdsada', id: 5, childs: [{name: 'zxc zx 111111111czx c', ids: 5 }]},
            {name: 'asdsadasd', id: 6, 
                child: [
                    {name: 'ccccc', ids: 6 },
                    {name: 'zxc zx czx cz', ids: 6 }
                ]
             },
        ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используя метод `.forEach()` перебираем каждый элемент массива `arr1`, получая его как `item`. Затем этому `item` определяем новое свойство `childs` в которое из массива `arr2` с помощью метода `filter` помещаем новый массив элементов, в которых `ids` совпадает с `item.id`.

```js
  const arr1 = [
    {name: 'aaaaa', id: 1 },
    {name: 'bbbbbb', id: 2 },
    {name: 'ccccc', id: 3 },
    {name: 'aaaasds', id: 4 },
    {name: 'asdsada', id: 5 },
    {name: 'asdsadasd', id: 6 },
  ]
const arr2 = [
    {name: 'adsaszzc123213', ids: 1 },
    {name: 'bbbbbb', ids: 1 },
    {name: 'ccccc', ids: 6 },
    {name: 'asdas dxc zz ', ids: 2 },
    {name: 'zxc zx czx c', ids: 2 },
    {name: 'zxc zx czx cz', ids: 6 },
    {name: 'adsaszzc123213', ids: 1 },
    {name: '111', ids: 1 },
    {name: 'ccccc', ids: 3 },
    {name: 'zxc dxc zz ', ids: 3 },
    {name: 'zxc zx 111111111czx c', ids: 5 },
    {name: 'zxc zx czx cz', ids: 4 },
  ]

arr1.forEach(item => {item.childs = arr2.filter(i => i.ids === item.id);});
console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение без лишних вложенных циклов, в 2 прохода (по одному на каждый массив):

```js
const arr1 = [
  { name: 'aaaaa', id: 1 },
  { name: 'bbbbbb', id: 2 },
  { name: 'ccccc', id: 3 },
  { name: 'aaaasds', id: 4 },
  { name: 'asdsada', id: 5 },
  { name: 'asdsadasd', id: 6 },
];
const arr2 = [
  { name: 'adsaszzc123213', ids: 1 },
  { name: 'bbbbbb', ids: 1 },
  { name: 'ccccc', ids: 6 },
  { name: 'asdas dxc zz ', ids: 2 },
  { name: 'zxc zx czx c', ids: 2 },
  { name: 'zxc zx czx cz', ids: 6 },
  { name: 'adsaszzc123213', ids: 1 },
  { name: '111', ids: 1 },
  { name: 'ccccc', ids: 3 },
  { name: 'zxc dxc zz ', ids: 3 },
  { name: 'zxc zx 111111111czx c', ids: 5 },
  { name: 'zxc zx czx cz', ids: 4 },
];

const map = arr1.reduce(
  (m, item1) => m.set(item1.id, Object.assign(item1, { childs: [] }))
, new Map());
for (const item2 of arr2)
  map.get(item2.ids).childs.push(item2);

console.log(arr1);
```

Именно в данном случае, сокращение числа проходов может дать улучшение в скорости только если избавиться от "паразитных" вызовов и создания временного объекта (да и то не гарантированно) - но это детали, которые не должны отвлекать от главной мысли: *задачи подобные этой, возможно решить в два прохода, если использовать хэштаблицу для индексации элементов по полю группировки значений*.

Comment: @Leonid, хз, наверное оптимизации движка JS, они ведь для того и делаются чтобы ускорять изначально медленные операции. И/или из-за того что мой пример далеко непоказательный в плане производительности: в нем на каждой итерации создается временный объект (а это медленная операция, т.к. связана с выделением памяти в куче), да и вызовы `assign` / `set` / `push` тоже могут тормозить (вызовов в циклах желательно избегать). Но ответ все-таки про общую идею использования хэштаблицы для сокращения числа проходов в множестве подобных задач, а не о скорости одного частного примера.

Comment: Нет, там все нормально, когда я в сотни раз увеличил входные данные эффект проявился. Вам метод быстрее.

Comment: @Leonid, да, прелести доступа по индексу проявляются при многократном обращении к большому кол-ву элементов. А когда элементов мало - доля накладных расходов (и неоптимальностей, как в моем примере) растет _процентно_, и складывается впечатление что все будто бы медленно и уныло. Только вот при малом кол-ве элементов, абсолютная разница измеряется миллисекундами которые ничего не решают даже при различии в несколько раз. Другими словами, использование ХТ дает незначительное ухудшение при малых объемах "поисковых" обращений, и значительное улучшение - на больших. Конечно, второе не бесплатно :)